# apostrophes and quotes unification? unicode

Tags: php, mysql, database, unicode

I had some bugs with strings coming in from MAC and PC and mobile devices, when compared to the ones on the database.

```
Smiths' ≠ Smiths`
```

Then I realized that there were more than just the `',"` I am used to... `׳‘’'` and `“”״"`.
Now, when being compared to the DB, I obviously thought of making some unification functions into the DB, and on the devices (PC,MAC, mobiles) to make the devices also realize a single `',"`.

Is there any obvious approach to the problem that I might be missing out here?

Comment: This is far too broad, and it starts from non-programming questions: how do you decide which characters should be “unified” with some other characters, treated as the same? How are you going to decide when a grave accent (`) is just a typo or a poor man’s substitute for a quote or an apostrophe and not really mean to be a grave? *Which* quote or apostrophe would you take it for? Are you considering how to “fix” input text by general rules? Or how to match incoming data with some entries in a database?

Comment: Since supporting several languages in my project is key, I actually thought this might be a well known issue. Until someone has come up with a better idea or concept, I will stick along with obvious functions